# Getting a django view python dict into highcharts series data

Tags: django, dictionary, highcharts

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to take a python dict that I have in a django view and get that into a pie chart series in highcharts.  Specifically, when I click on a point in one chart on my page, I'm trying to load a second chart with detailed data on that point.

For example, I might have a column chart with inventory for 'fruit', 'meat', 'vegetables'.  If I click on a column, a second chart displays the inventory breakdown.  AKA The second 'fruit' chart would show the inventory for 'apples', 'oranges', 'bananas' in a pie graph.

I'm trying to do this with jQuery.get since I don't want to reload the entire page.  My django view would have a section for handling the ajax that looks something like this:

```
myData = {}
myData['apples'] = 20
myData['oranges'] = 30
myData['bananas'] = 50

context = Context()
context['fruit'] = myData
return HttpResponse(context)
```

The data format that I'd like to use for the pie chart has the dict key as the x and dict value as the y:

```
[['apples',20],['oranges',30]…]
```

I've tried just passing the data as a string from the view to script, and while that gets across the wire correctly as a string, is not handled the way I want because I think the values 20, 30 etc are handled as strings and not values.  I'm not sure if this is the right way at all.
Should I be doing this by rendering the context in a django template?  If so, how would something like that look like inside a jQuery/ajax success handler?

It seems like going from a dict to a highcharts series with the aforementioned format (with the dict key as the x and dict value as the y)  would be something that many folks have done so I think I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

myData = {}
myData['apples'] = 20
myData['oranges'] = 30
myData['bananas'] = 50

response_data = {
  'data': myData,
  'message': 'OK',
  'status': 'success'
}

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This really helped me get what I needed.  I ended up tweaking things and used a python list instead of dict since a pie chart is a bit particular if you want to show the x value as a label for the slice, but getting the data there worked exactly as you described.

Comment: @StephenWang - thanks! I was struggling with a similar question. It seems Highcharts can't really accept series data if sent as dict (via JSON) (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#1). Do you agree? 
I had to use lists (because of this reason) even when dict made more sense in my use case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using django >= 1.7, [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) will be a better choice.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def my_data(request):
    myData = {}
    myData['apples'] = 20
    myData['oranges'] = 30
    myData['bananas'] = 50
    return JsonResponse(myData, safe=False)
```

Comment: +1 for the update for >=1.7. Same question for you as above. It seems Highcharts can't really accept series data if sent as dict (via JSON) (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series#1). Do you agree? 
I had to use lists (because of this reason) even when dict made more sense in my use case.